# How can I get current keyboard language from a service?

Tags: android

I want to make a layout icon for Android phones with QWERTY keyboards, however Android policy concerning `InputMethodManager` is pretty strict, so I am trying to get the current language via the Accessibility, but I am stuck since the provided `AccessibilityService.SoftKeyboardController` can only tell you if the keyboard is shown. 
Any ideas on how I can get the current layout from a service?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround - when the layout changes a Toast notification is shown, so I've resorted to catching these notifications. It's a hack, but it works.